# Evaporate.js pause/resume

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, upload, evaporate.js

I am using Evaporate.js to upload files to Amazon Web Service .

https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS
This is working fine,But i need to add pause/resume features to my application.Is it possible?

I notice that some empty functions are there in https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS/blob/master/evaporate.js

```
 _.pause = function(id){

 };

 _.resume = function(id){

 };

 _.forceRetry = function(){

 };
```

Is  any way to do with this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the maintainer of EvaporateJS. As of v1.5.0, Evaporate implemented pause/resume.

There is stable, rewritten version 2.0 that is available that improves on that support, but if you want to be on the stable latest release descendent from v1.5.0, you should install v1.6.3 for that support.

I would strongly recommend using v2.0.1.

Comment: thanks,But when i start  to implement this,the pause and resume is not available